# How to get react dynamic background Image value in style?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

I return dynamic value from database as JSON data. I can't set value to backgroundImage tag. I tried code in blow

```
images = imageList.map(img => {
  return (
    <div
      key={img.id}
      style={{
         backgroundImage: `https://blabla.com/image/${img.icon}` //Don't work
      }}>
    </div>
  );
}); }
```

Comment: can you give us more details? your entire component and the network request/response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use css syntax with backgroundImage

```
images = imageList.map(img => {
  return (
    <div
      key={img.id}
      style={{
         backgroundImage: `url("https://blabla.com/image/${img.icon}")` //Should work
      }}>
    </div>
  );
}); }
```